# Pepper spray for dogs

Tags: home

I am looking for a diy project to protect myself against "rogue" dogs.

I was bitten by a dog while bike riding.

The dog bit thru some blue jeans and drew blood.

I live in a apartment and aggressive dogs are a low priority.

How can I make some dog propellant that I can spray on rogue dogs.

Comment: To help with the legal side of it, in which part of the world do you live? (In the USA a lot more is allowed than in most of Europe, for instance.) And as a  different approach, see the answers on this question over at bicycles: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-to-fend-off-a-pack-of-feral-dogs and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/85828/pack-of-dogs-best-response-to-owner

Comment: You're already set on pepper spray, so just buy it, I'm not sure what you expect to get here. Lifehack can be using something **else**.

Comment: @Willeke   § 3-17. Running at-large prohibited.
(a) Violation provisions, generally.No owner or keeper of any domestic animal shall
permit or allow such domestic animal to run at-large within the limits of the city.
The owner or keeper of any domestic animal running at-large shall be in violation
of this article.
(b) At large; unattended in vehicle.Unattended domestic animal in open vehicles shall

Answer (score 0):

**Pepper spray for dangerous animals?**

Hope you do not mind me changing the heading in this posts, because dogs are only the tip of the iceberg when it comes to being attacked by wild, feral or rogue animals.

First of all, what is pepper spray?

> [Pepper spray](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_spray), oleoresin capsicum spray, OC spray, capsaicin spray, or capsicum spray is a lachrymatory agent (a compound that irritates the eyes to cause a burning sensation, pain, and temporary blindness) used in policing, riot control, crowd control, and self-defense, including defense against dogs and bears. Its inflammatory effects cause the eyes to close, temporarily taking away vision. This temporary blindness allows officers to more easily restrain subjects and permits people in danger to use pepper spray in self-defense for an opportunity to escape. It also causes temporary discomfort and burning of the lungs which causes shortness of breath.
>
> Pepper spray was engineered into a spray originally for defense against bears, mountain lions, wolves and **other dangerous predators**, and is often referred to colloquially as ***bear spray***.

It is nevertheless possible to make homemade pepper spray from things easily available around the house.

Here is what you need:

> - Put 2 tbsp (30 g) of cayenne pepper in a bowl and cover it with rubbing alcohol. Add 1 tbsp (15 g) of vegetable oil and let it steep overnight.
> - Strain out the solids with a coffee filter or cheesecloth, reserving the pepper liquid.
> - Drill a hole in an empty spray deodorant can and transfer the pepper liquid into it.
> - Alternatively, transfer the liquid to a regular spray bottle.

How to mix the ingredients together can be found here: [How to Make Pepper Spray](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Pepper-Spray#tips) It actually looks quite easy to put together!

More information can be gleaned from the following posts:

- [How to fend off a pack of feral dogs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-to-fend-off-a-pack-of-feral-dogs)
- [Pack of dogs - best response to owner?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/85828/pack-of-dogs-best-response-to-owner)

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I found this. Can I pepper spray a dog in Texas?

No. Anyone can carry pepper spray. There is no licensing requirement, and there’s no place that’s exempted by law in the State of Texas where you cannot carry that pepper spray.
Источник: https://midogguide.com/dog-breeds/is-it-illegal-to-spray-a-dog-with-pepper-spray.html @Ken Graham